# WordPress rewrite url (remove category)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I AM trying to change url in wordpress root .htaccess

The URL is 
http://www.demoain/category/blog

And i want to rewrite url from this one
http://www.demoain/blog

Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog$ /category/blog [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /category/blog/$1 [L]
```